# How do I change the calendar language?

Tags: 13.04, language-support, calendar

I installed ubuntu 13.04 with the default language English, yet the calendar is displayed in local language ( Arabic ) , is there a way to change the calendar language to English ?

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can add an image of that?

Comment: @Mitch, I had to read a Gimp tutorial to crop images ! I'll need a lot of time to get used to Ubuntu after all these years of using windows :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to System Settings, then to Language Support. From there open the second tab which is 
named "Regional Formats". Then change the drop down bar's content from "Arabic" to the English language variant you like and you're all set.

Re-login for this to take effect